# How to use docker with gradle while having private docker registry server

Tags: docker, gradle, docker-registry

I am trying to setup https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/#initial with my environment, which has a private registry server @

```
el-qa-docker.x.x.x:18445
```

my build.gradle has the following relevant content:

```
dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.3.RELEASE")
        classpath('se.transmode.gradle:gradle-docker:1.2')
        classpath ('org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-backports-compat23:2.3.5')
    }

group = 'james'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'docker'

task buildDocker(type: Docker, dependsOn: build) {
  push = true
  applicationName = jar.baseName
  dockerfile = file('src/main/docker/Dockerfile')
  doFirst {
    copy {
      from jar
      into stageDir
    }
  }
}
```

when I run: `$gradle build buildDock`

I get build FAILURE, with:

```
    $ gradle build buildDock
    :compileJava UP-TO-DATE
    :processResources UP-TO-DATE
    :classes UP-TO-DATE
    :findMainClass
    :jar
    :bootRepackage
    :assemble
    :compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
    :processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
    :testClasses UP-TO-DATE
    :test UP-TO-DATE
    :check UP-TO-DATE
    :build
    :buildDocker FAILED

    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':buildDocker'.
    > Docker execution failed
      Command line [docker build -t skahmed/gs-spring-boot-docker:latest /Users/skahmed/devops/TOOLS/DOCKER/gs-spring-boot-docker/initial/build/docker] returned:
      Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)


    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 16.243 secs
```

any ideas, on where do I specify docker's internal registry which can be used with Gradle.

I tried:

```
docker {
  useApi true
  hostUrl 'el-qa-docker.x.x.x:18445'
  apiUsername 'james'
}
```

as provided by https://github.com/Transmode/gradle-docker

but that gives a different error:

```
 $ gradle build buildDock
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:findMainClass
:jar
:bootRepackage
:assemble
:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:test UP-TO-DATE
:check UP-TO-DATE
:build
:buildDocker FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':buildDocker'.
> Port is invalid: -1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1.389 secs
```

I tried : build.gradle

```
docker {
   //useApi true
   hostUrl 'el2-dt-docker.uscis.dhs.gov:18445'
   apiUsername 'skahmed'
}
```

and

```
task buildDocker(type: Docker, dependsOn: build) {
  push = true
  applicationName = jar.baseName
  //applicationName = 'el2-dt-docker.uscis.dhs.gov:18445/skahmed/gs-spring-boot-docker'
  //applicationName = 'gs-spring-boot-docker'
  dockerfile = file('src/main/docker/Dockerfile')
  doFirst {
    copy {
      from jar
      into stageDir
    }
  }
}
```

but get:

```
:buildDocker FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':buildDocker'.
> Docker execution failed
  Command line [docker push skahmed/gs-spring-boot-docker:latest] returned:
  Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify your private Docker registry as part of your Docker image name e.g.:

```
el-qa-docker.x.x.x:18445/skahmed/gs-spring-boot-docker
```

Please make sure your Docker daemon is aware about private registry.

Comment: Where would I specify this registry? i.e in the Dockerfile, or build.gradle? in task buildDocker() I changed push = false and got the build working, but I still cannot push to my local registry